# Custom Unity mouse input with WM_INPUT - receiving weird values

Tags: c#, windows, mouse

## About

I am trying to get the raw mouse input of the system into a C# application. I am using `WM_INPUT` ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418864(v=vs.85).aspx)) to get access to the data. To do so I am using the user32.dll. This ([stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27866645/registering-a-touch-screen-hid-with-registerrawinputdevices-does-not-work)) helped me alot with writing the API Wrapper. I do this because I want to try if there is any difference (when using my own custom mouse input) to the Unity API that gives me raw mouse input. I hope that's reason enough to post here at "Game Development".

## Current approach

The following snippet shows the `WndProc` method. `rimTypeMouseCount` already shows that the windows messages seem to get fetched correctly. When I turn the polling rate of my mouse up or down I can see this also by checking the count - Lower polling rate means a lower count, higher polling rate means a higher count while logging for equal time intervals. That's good so far.

#### WndProc callback method:

```cs
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == 0x00ff) {
        uint dwSize = 40;

        byte[] raw = new byte[40];
        IntPtr rawPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(raw.Length);

        APIWrapper.GetRawInputData((IntPtr)m.LParam, 0x10000003, rawPtr, ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(new APIWrapper.RAWINPUTHEADER()));

        Marshal.Copy(rawPtr, raw, 0, 40);

        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(raw, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        APIWrapper.RAWINPUT rawData = (APIWrapper.RAWINPUT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(APIWrapper.RAWINPUT));
        handle.Free();

        if (rawData.header.dwType == 0)
        {
            rimTypeMouseCount++;
            logMouseX = logMouseX + rawData.mouse.lLastX.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            logMouseY = logMouseY + rawData.mouse.lLastY.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

#### RAWINPUT struct:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct RAWINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public RAWINPUTHEADER header;

        [FieldOffset(16 + 8)]
        public RAWMOUSE mouse;

        [FieldOffset(16 + 8)]
        public RAWKEYBOARD keyboard;

        [FieldOffset(16 + 8)]
        public RAWHID hid;
    }
```

## Problem

But there is a problem with `logMouseX` and `logMouseY`. Those to strings simply append the mouse deltas of the x and y axis with every call. Unfortunately `logMouseX` only logs the values 0 or 65535 while `logMouseY` logs 0 only. I also tried to log messages like left mouse button up/down and so on. Nothing seems to work actually. For me it seems a little that the numbers might be random or something like that.

## Question

This is what I (think I) do:

1. `APIWrapper.GetRawInputData(...)` needs a pointer to a byte array. So I simply allocated space in unmanaged memory with marshalling and got a pointer as a result.
2. I am calling the function that fills the array the pointer is pointing at.
3. I am taking the pointer that points to the filled array and copy its content into an actual byte array.
4. To access the fields of the struct `RAWINPUT` I need to cast the byte array to a `RAWINPUT` struct.
5. I do this with the three lines that use a GCHandle. I actually found that snippet somewhere but never worked with that class before.

Might it be that I am messing up something there? Maybe something like a Big-Endian and Little-Endian mix up?

## Notes

- I found out that the values I get when using `rawData.mouse.lLastX` & `rawData.mouse.lLastY` behave like this:

  - X is zero when moving the mouse downwards and 65535 when moving upwards
  - Y is zero always no matter if I move the mouse left or right
- I found out that using `rawDataL.hid.pbRawData` includes more information about the movement. There I get values in dependency of how fast I am moving the mouse. Unfortunately there is no X or Y component so this only works for one axis (downwards/upwards).
- I found a simpler way of casts. Unfortunately I still get the stranges values as described above. It looks like this now:

#### Casting part of WndProc:

```cs
uint dwSize = 40;

byte[] raw = new byte[40];
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(raw, GCHandleType.Pinned);

APIWrapper.GetRawInputData((IntPtr)m.LParam, 0x10000003, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), ref dwSize, Marshal.SizeOf(new APIWrapper.RAWINPUTHEADER()));

APIWrapper.RAWINPUT rawData = (APIWrapper.RAWINPUT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(APIWrapper.RAWINPUT));

if (rawData.header.dwType == 0)
{
    // accessing data
}

handle.Free();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question here ([MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f33f4f2-67ac-4dee-bf93-902433ff3e43/weird-values-from-wminput?forum=vclanguage)) and I was told that the offsets of the RAWMOUSE struct are not correct.

So I simply logged all bytes of the raw data array and finally could see all the data I need and therefore the correct offsets. I guess the offsets differ when using 32 bit or 64 bit machines. Here are the relevant code changes:

WndProc changes:

```cs
RawMouseData rawData = (RawMouseData) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(RawMouseData));
```

RawMouseData struct:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct RawMouseData
{
    [FieldOffset(20)]
    public ButtonFlags buttonFlags;
    [FieldOffset(22)]
    public ushort buttonData;
    [FieldOffset(28)]
    public int lastX;
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public int lastY;
}
```

This is how the data log of the raw byte array looks like for each mouse movement direction:

```
Downwards:      Upwards:
Byte 29: 0      Byte 29: 0 
Byte 30: 0      Byte 30: 0 
Byte 31: 0      Byte 31: 0 
Byte 32: 0      Byte 32: 0 
Byte 33: 1      Byte 33: 255 
Byte 34: 0      Byte 34: 255 
Byte 35: 0      Byte 35: 255 
Byte 36: 0      Byte 36: 255

Left:           Right:
Byte 29: 255    Byte 29: 1 
Byte 30: 255    Byte 30: 0 
Byte 31: 255    Byte 31: 0 
Byte 32: 255    Byte 32: 0 
Byte 33: 0      Byte 33: 0 
Byte 34: 0      Byte 34: 0 
Byte 35: 0      Byte 35: 0 
Byte 36: 0      Byte 36: 0
```

The faster I move the mouse the bigger (when moving downwards or right) or smaller (when moving upwards or left) the values get.